Formatting Pages when Printing
I try to print a report but i have some problem when formatting header and pages.
This is an example:
enter image description here
The ID to display are 39.
I'd like to have a multiple pages print and header on each page.
this is my code now:
private void printDocument1_PrintPage(object sender, System.Drawing.Printing.PrintPageEventArgs e)
{
    string IMAGE = "";
    sqlite.Open();  //Initiate connection to the db
    string stm = "SELECT VALORE FROM IMPOSTAZIONI WHERE IMPOSTAZIONE = 'LOGO';";
    using var cmd = new SQLiteCommand(stm, sqlite);
    using SQLiteDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    while (rdr.Read())
    {
        IMAGE = (string)rdr["VALORE"];
    }
    sqlite.Close();

    Image bgFront = Image.FromFile(@"Immagini\" + IMAGE);
    e.Graphics.DrawImage(bgFront, 50, 0, 100, 100);
    e.Graphics.DrawString("Report Movimenti in Uscita non Pagati", new Font("Courier New", 18, FontStyle.Bold), Brushes.Black, new PointF(210, 40));
    e.Graphics.DrawString(richTextBox1.Text, new Font("Courier New", 14, FontStyle.Bold), Brushes.Black, new PointF(50, 150));
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (printPreviewDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        printDocument1.DefaultPageSettings.Landscape = true;
        printDocument1.Print();
    }
}

private void printPreviewDialog1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    printDocument1.DefaultPageSettings.Landscape = true;
}

Can you help me format this report correctly?
I'd like to have a multiple pages print and header on each page.

What is a multiple pages print and header?

you haven't done any printing of the page table content. Most likely that is the task of the assignment, do some work yourself first.

You should presumably: 1, use the Page/MarginBounds so you know where you can write, and how much you can write per page. 2. Measure text size before drawing so you know the string fits. 3, Set HasMorePages to false when you have printed all pages. 4, keep track of what you have written, so you can continue where you left of from the previous page.

Or perhaps you should just convert your data to some other document format, like html, that lets you use an existing layout/rendering engine instead of needing to write all of that yourself.

To read data from SQLite and append each item as a new row to RichTextBox.
And to print the contents of the RichTextBox to multiple pages with headers and display 30 rows of data per page, you could try to refer to the following sample code.
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        CreateDatabase();
        CreateTable();
        for (int i = 0; i < 40; i++)
        {
            InsertData($"LOGO{i}", $"logo_value_{i}");

        }
        PopulateRichTextBox();
    }
 
 

    public void CreateDatabase()
    {
        SQLiteConnection.CreateFile("MyDatabase.sqlite");
     
    }
    public void PopulateRichTextBox()
    {
        using (SQLiteConnection connection = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source=MyDatabase.sqlite"))
        {
            connection.Open();
            string sql = "SELECT * FROM IMPOSTAZIONI";
        
            using (SQLiteCommand command = new SQLiteCommand(sql, connection))
            {
               
                using (SQLiteDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                      
                        string impostazione = reader.GetString(reader.GetOrdinal("impostazione"));
                        string valore = reader.GetString(reader.GetOrdinal("valore"));

                      
                        richTextBox1.AppendText($"{impostazione}: {valore}\n");
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    }
    public void CreateTable()
    {
        using (SQLiteConnection connection = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source=MyDatabase.sqlite"))
        {
            connection.Open();
            string sql = " CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS IMPOSTAZIONI (Id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, IMPOSTAZIONE varchar(20), VALORE varchar(20)) ";
            SQLiteCommand command = new SQLiteCommand(sql, connection);
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();

          

            connection.Close();
        }

      
    }

    public void InsertData(string impostazione, string valore)
    {
        using (SQLiteConnection connection = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source=MyDatabase.sqlite"))
        {
            connection.Open();
            string sql = "INSERT INTO IMPOSTAZIONI (IMPOSTAZIONE, VALORE) VALUES (@impostazione, @valore)";
            using (SQLiteCommand command = new SQLiteCommand(sql, connection))
            {
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@impostazione", impostazione);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@valore", valore);
                command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }
    }

    private int currentPageIndex = 0;
    private List<string> pagesContent;
    private string headerText = "Id\tIMPOSTAZIONE\tVALORE";
    private void PreparePagesContent()
    {
        string allText = richTextBox1.Text;
        int linesPerPage = 30;
        List<string> lines = new List<string>(allText.Split(new[] { '\n' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries));
        pagesContent = new List<string>();

        for (int i = 0; i < lines.Count; i += linesPerPage)
        {
            List<string> pageLines = lines.Skip(i).Take(linesPerPage).ToList();
            StringBuilder pageContent = new StringBuilder();
            foreach (string line in pageLines)
            {
                pageContent.AppendLine(line);
            }
            pagesContent.Add(pageContent.ToString());
        }
    }

    private void printDocument1_BeginPrint(object sender, System.Drawing.Printing.PrintEventArgs e)
    {
        PreparePagesContent();
        currentPageIndex = 0; 
    }

    private void printDocument1_PrintPage(object sender, System.Drawing.Printing.PrintPageEventArgs e)
    {
        string pageContent = pagesContent[currentPageIndex];

        e.Graphics.DrawString(headerText, new Font("Arial", 10, FontStyle.Bold), Brushes.Black, new PointF(50, 50));

        e.Graphics.DrawString(pageContent, new Font("Arial", 10), Brushes.Black, new PointF(50, 80));

        currentPageIndex++; 

        e.HasMorePages = (currentPageIndex < pagesContent.Count);
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (printPreviewDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            printDocument1.DefaultPageSettings.Landscape = true;
            printDocument1.Print();
        }
    }
    private void printPreviewDialog1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        printPreviewDialog1.Document = printDocument1;
        printDocument1.DefaultPageSettings.Landscape = true;
    }
}


Thank's now it's ok
